# How can I convert MATLAB image processing library build-in function to c++ that is not supported by matlab coder code generation?

Tags: c++, matlab

How can I convert built-in functions like imagesc and bwareafilt to c++/c code that are not supported for code generation by Matlab coder?

Comment: Odds are good you'll have to find or write replacement libraries, but I'm sure you knew that already. I recommend tightening up your question in order to get less trivial answers. Note that it is off topic to make library requests here, but you can ask over at [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: can't you convert with the MEX converter.

Comment: Can you guide me on how this can be done with mex converter?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not supported by the Matlab Coder , manual conversion may be the option.
You can use OpenCV for C++ . Here is a cheat sheet that links Matlab Commands and equivalent OpenCV commands .

https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/blob/master/doc/CheatSheet/cheatsheet.pdf?raw=true

I have personally converted Matlab Code to OpenCV code manually.

Though simple functions are similar in both , Matlab offers complex ones like imfindcircles , imagesc etc which may not be available as a single line command in OpenCv as it would be in Matlab.

For this , read the .m file of the specific function in matlab , understand the logic and try to convert it or just google that algorithm . Do this in steps , write down the pseudocode / algo and then try to convert it .

It works !